# Android: How to make item in ListView clickable

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, button, clickable

I am currently attempting to make a ListView List in order to load the contact into the aforementioned list. However, the contact entry is not clickable. I try to use a solution in an unidentified website; I may be doing something wrong.

#### ContactManager.java

```
package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public final class ContactManager extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

    private Button mAddAccountButton;
    private ListView mContactList;
    private boolean mShowInvisible;
    //public BooleanObservable ShowInvisible = new BooleanObservable(false);
    private CheckBox mShowInvisibleControl;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing the UI.
     */
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        
         mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
         mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
         
        Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);

        // Obtain handles to UI objects
        mAddAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mShowInvisibleControl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInvisible);

        // Initialise class properties
        mShowInvisible = false;
        mShowInvisibleControl.setChecked(mShowInvisible);

        // Register handler for UI elements
        mAddAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
                launchContactAdder();
            }
        });
        mShowInvisibleControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "mShowInvisibleControl changed: " + isChecked);
                mShowInvisible = isChecked;
                populateContactList();
            }
        })
        
        
        
        ;

        // Populate the contact list
        populateContactList();
    }

    /**
     * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
     */
    private void populateContactList() {
        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        String[] fields = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
                fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
        mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
     *
     * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
     */
    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the ContactAdder activity to add a new contact to the selected account.
     */
    protected void launchContactAdder()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactAdder.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("TAG", "You clicked item " + id + " at position " + position);
        // Here you start the intent to show the contact details
    }
    
    
}
```

#### contact_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/contactEntryText"
              android:id="@+id/contactEntryText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:textSize="30sp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The aforementioned code is not functioning as I would like it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by implementing the `OnItemClickListener` and handle the clicks in the method `onItemClick`. You also need to tell your mContactList to use the Listener (thx Sam):

```
public final class ContactManager extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       [...]
       mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
       mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       [...]

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("TAG", "You clicked item " + id + " at position " + position);
        // Here you start the intent to show the contact details
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to tell the ListView to use this listener: `mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: Oh, missed that. Thank you for the hint. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have to set  OnItemClickListener for the listview 'mContactList " and you can navigate him to next activity using intent. Hope this helps you.

You can check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/